# intellisense for processing

Tags: processing, processing.js, processing-ide

I am developing a code in processing language and to make it a web application I am using processing.js.

I was wondering if there is any intellisense for processing ide or if there is an IDE for processing which has intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an Eclipse-style outline you could try the Sketch-Outline tool for Processing 2.0: http://code.google.com/p/sketch-outline/

I have not tested this myself, but the screenshot posted here looks promising:
https://forum.processing.org/topic/sketch-outline-new-processing-tool-announcement

Personally I use Eclipse as a full-fledged IDE, giving you auto-complete, class outline etc. The only downside is that you have to lose some of the code fudging done by the Processing pre-compiler, i.e. "color" does not exist as a variable type (it's really an int) and float numbers need to be suffixed with "f" - "2.0" in Java is a double, "2.0f" is a float.

Comment: Thanks. Sketch outline is a useful tool for me. However, the reason I don't use eclipse is that, my project is also working with processig.js and is a web application. Is there any way to use eclipse and processing.js at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliSense is just Microsoft's implementation of autocomplete.

I'm guessing that you're looking for a Processing IDE (not a Processing.JS IDE) with autocomplete.

Here is one recommendation:
http://wiki.processing.org/w/JEdit_as_External_IDE

If you're looking for a Processing.js IDE, there are two listed here:

http://processingjs.org/

They are:

http://sketchpad.cc/

http://processingjs.org/tools/processing-helper.html

Comment: Yes what I need is a processing IDE with intellisense. I actually have several classes and I want an IDE to show me the functions and variables of each Object through other classes. does Jedit support that?

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can use [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) with the [Proclipsing](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) plugin which is cross platform and easy to setup.

I presume you can get auto complete with any other Java IDE like NetBeans or IntelliJ Idea, it's a matter of linking Processing's core.jar and subclassing [PApplet](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html).

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (commercial) offers partial autocompletion for .pde processing sketches.